# Nice inequality involving two tuples of real numbers

Tags: inequality

I posted an inequality few days ago, but I realized later on that it could only holds under stronger constraints. In particular I reduced such inequality to the inequality I am posting here. I think it is nice and I would really pleased if someone could give me any some suggestion. I simulated it with million of combinations and it always held. Thanks in advance!

Consider two tuples each of $n$ positive real numbers $(x_1, x_2, ...x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ and two real numbers $q \in (0,1)$ and $\beta \in (0,1)$. If
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{q}{\beta x_i}} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1-q}{(1-\beta) y_i}},
$$
is it true that the inequality below holds?$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{q}{\beta x_i}} \geq \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{\beta x_i + (1-\beta) y_i}}.
$$

Comment: Is there a typo? $q=0$ is a counterexample to both the equality and the inequality.

Comment: The equality seems to be a given condition.

Comment: @enricopiovano Your proposed inequality has nothing to do directly with the three inequalities you tagged, please don't misuse tags.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco : thanks a lot to let me know, I am very sorry

Comment: @StellaBiderman for $q=0$, may consider $\beta=0$ and find an undertermined form. However, you are completely right, it is better to consider both $q \in (0,1)$ and $\beta \in (0,1)$. Let me modify the exercise. AlexFrancisco is completely right. the equality gives you a condition, and based on the condition you need to prove the inequality.

Comment: @EnricoPiovano Your question doesn’t say “for all q there exists a $\beta$” it says “for all $q$ and $\beta$.” These are very different things.

Comment: @EnricoPiovano Oh, are we assuming the equality holds? That wasn’t clear to me.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: exactly, we assume that $q$ and $\beta$ are such that the equality holds. It is not about existence of certain $q, \beta$, but only about assuming that such equality holds. I modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy's inequality,$$
(βx_k + (1 - β)y_k)\left( \frac{q^2}{βx_k} + \frac{(1 - q)^2}{(1 - β)y_k} \right) \geqslant (q + (1 - q))^2 = 1,
$$
i.e.$$
\frac{q^2}{βx_k} + \frac{(1 - q)^2}{(1 - β)y_k} \geqslant \frac{1}{βx_k + (1 - β)y_k}. \quad 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n
$$

Note that$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{q}{βx_k} = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1 - q}{(1 - β)y_k},
$$
thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{q}{βx_k} &= q \cdot \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{q}{βx_k} + (1 - q) \cdot \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1 - q}{(1 - β)y_k}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n \left( \frac{q^2}{βx_k} + \frac{(1 - q)^2}{(1 - β)y_k} \right)\\
&\geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{βx_k + (1 - β)y_k}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a very elegant solution ! Really thanks a lot @AlexFrancisco, very very appreciated.